Laravel Octane with FrankenPHP crashes with status 139 after running for a few hours
I’m using Laravel Octane in my development environment, and the application crashes after running for a few hours. When it crashes, I only get status 139, which I understand is a segmentation fault (SIGSEGV). There are no other error logs or explanations provided for the crash.
I’ve set up error logging and have tried to debug the issue, but I’m unable to track down the exact cause of the segmentation fault.
What did you try and what were you expecting?
I have tried several things to identify and resolve the issue:

Checked system logs to see if there were any related memory or CPU usage spikes.
Set up custom error logging in Laravel to catch any unexpected errors, but nothing shows up in the logs.
Restarted Octane and cleared caches multiple times, but the issue still occurs.
Monitored the environment for potential issues like memory leaks or resource exhaustion.

I expected the application to either:

Run smoothly without crashing, or
Log an error message or provide more details on what’s causing the crash.

However, all I get is status 139 (segmentation fault), and nothing useful is logged to help debug the problem.
Additional Information
I'm running Laravel Octane as a systemctl service with the following configuration:
[Unit]
Description=Laravel Octane
After=network.target

[Service]
User=leensite
Group=leensite
WorkingDirectory=/home/leensite/domains/api.deleensite.nl/
ExecStart=/usr/local/php83/bin/php /home/leensite/domains/api.deleensite.nl/artisan octane:start --server=frankenphp --admin-port=8017 --watch
Restart=always
RestartSec=5
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=laravel-octane

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target



-- Logs begin at Sat 2024-10-19 00:36:59 CEST. --
okt 21 12:47:08 diana..com laravel-octane[3179888]:   Press Ctrl+C to stop the server
okt 21 15:37:41 diana..com systemd[1]: Stopping Laravel Octane...
okt 21 15:37:41 diana..com systemd[1]: laravel-octane-leensite.service: Succeeded.
okt 21 15:37:41 diana..com systemd[1]: Stopped Laravel Octane.
okt 21 15:37:49 diana..com systemd[1]: Started Laravel Octane.
okt 21 15:37:50 diana..com laravel-octane[3332275]:    INFO  Server running….
okt 21 15:37:50 diana..com laravel-octane[3332275]:   Local: http://127.0.0.1:3015
okt 21 15:37:50 diana..com laravel-octane[3332275]:   Press Ctrl+C to stop the server
okt 22 12:52:32 diana..com systemd[1]: laravel-octane-leensite.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=139/n/a
okt 22 12:52:32 diana..com systemd[1]: laravel-octane-leensite.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.


It can be a memory leak issue. It’s hard to tell exactly what it's causing it but check for any recursive calls or self-referencing functions in your code. You can start debugging by commenting out parts of your code that might involve complex loops or relations. Also, monitor memory usage to see if it grows over time.

I have observed that the memory usage increases progressively over time with each execution. This issue appears to result in higher and higher memory consumption after each cycle, suggesting a possible memory leak or inefficient resource handling. It is only really hard to know where this issue is happening thats why I would like to have some better logging.

You might consider increasing the memory_limit. How much do you currently have set? Don’t rely on this solution to mask underlying issues. If you find yourself needing more and more memory frequently there's something wrong
